# How can I force make to re-evaluate prerequisites?

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to write a Makefile that automatically calls BibTeX on files that match a specific wildcard but don't exist when I first run Make. Specifically, I have the following:

```
.FORCE:

all: pdf

foo=something

lat: *.tex
    pdflatex $(foo).tex

pdf: lat
    open $(foo).pdf &

%.aux: .FORCE
    bibtex $@

bib: lat $(foo)?.aux
    pdflatex $(foo).tex
    pdflatex $(foo).tex
    open $(foo).pdf &
```

What I want to happen is that the following will occur when I run `make bib`:

- pdflatex will be called on $(foo).tex, generating files $(foo)1.aux, $(foo)2.aux, etc.
- bibtex will be called on $(foo)1.aux, then $(foo)2.aux, etc.
- pdflatex will be called twice on $(foo).tex
- open will be called on $(foo).pdf

However, this doesn't happen: in particular, it looks as if Make evaluates the prerequisites $(foo)?.aux up-front, at a point where the files $(foo)1.aux, $(foo)2.aux, etc. don't exist. As a result, BibTeX is never called on them. If I rerun `make bib`, however, things work, because the files now exist after being created on the previous run.

**Question: Is forcing Make to re-evaluate prerequisites for a target the right way to fix this? If so, how can I get it to re-evaluate the prerequisites for bib after running pdflatex as part of lat? If not, how can I achieve what I want please?**

Comment: Use [rubber](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/12/building-documents-with-rubber/)

Comment: Is the number of auxilliary files variable — could be 1, or 2, or 10, or 200?  If so, then I'd most probably write a shell script to do the actions, and invoke that from the `makefile`.  I'm puzzled how invoking `pdflatex` on a file twice in a row would produce different results — but I've not used it, so there could be a reason for it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Thanks, I didn't know about that. It doesn't look like it works with `bibtopic` unfortunately (which I'm using), but I could potentially switch to `multibib`. Still slightly curious if what I'm trying to achieve is possible in Make as well, but this might be a potential solution to the practical problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The auxiliary files are generated by the first run of `pdflatex` - there's no trivial way of predicting in advance how many there will be (other than parsing the TeX source). Invoking `pdflatex` multiple times is a standard workflow when using LaTeX - it allows things like forward references to be properly resolved.

Comment: OK; thanks for the information.  I gleaned that something like that might be going on from looking at the rubber link.  Note that the comments after the blog entry mention multiple alternatives to rubber.  Back to this question: I don't think there's an easy way to force `make` into re-evaluating dependencies other than a complete re-invocation of `make` (which you could do: `${MAKE} bib` as an action after the command for the `lat` target is run).  The `lat` target is a 'phony' target; you don't create a file called `lat` AFAICT.

Comment: Iterating as long as the top-level *.log file changes (tested with diff) is a robust solution. I implemented YAMFL (Yet Another Makefile For LaTeX) that you can use as an example. Discard all the figures generation code (Xfig, dia, dot...) and you will quickly find the real LaTeX engine: https://github.com/pacalet/mli.git

Answer (score 0):

What I do in my `Maiefile` for LaTeX files is rename the targets.
That way, you can have different target names, depending on which phase has been used to create them. This is according to the spirit of `make`'s pattern rules, which assume that files with different contents also have different extensions.  So I have rules like this:

```
%.aux1 : %.tex
    rm -f $*.aux
    pdflatex -draftmode $*
    mv -f $*.aux $@

%.bbl : %.aux1
    cp -pf $< $*.aux
    bibtex $* || : > $@

%.aux2 : %.bbl
    cp -pf $*.aux1 $*.aux
    pdflatex -draftmode $*
    mv -f $*.aux $@

%-tex.pdf: %.aux2
    cp -pf $< $*.aux
    pdflatex -jobname $*-tex $*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in a completely straightforward way, since `make` fundamentally assumes that one run through a target's commands will update the target.  That is, there's no way in principle that you can tell `make` that ‘you need to run these commands twice’.

You can try to get round this with (admirably clever) tricks such as @reinerpost suggests, but a problem with that general approach is that sometimes/often a single run of BibTeX (or makeindex, or whatever) *is* sufficient.

After having tried various types of tricks in the past, what I generally do here is to make a command list which explicitly includes two BibTeX calls where necessary:

```
%.bbl: %.aux
    bibtex $(@:.bbl=)
    if grep -q Rerun $(@:.bbl=.log) >/dev/null; then \
      bibtex $(@:.bbl=); \
    fi
```

That command list re-runs BibTeX if the log file includes the ‘*Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right*’ message.

To be honest, what I *actually* do is just the single line `bibtex $(@:.bbl=)`.  When I'm writing a document, I inevitably re-run `make` so many times that the list of references comes out correct very quickly.  This means that this target doesn't work for the ‘recreate the final version from a clean directory’ case, but that's sufficiently rare that I tend not to obsess about it.

Whenever I catch myself re-solving this problem, I now recognise that I'm trying to push water up-hill because I'm bored writing this document, so I go and do something else.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to share an alternative solution: Using submake processes:

> If so, how can I get it to re-evaluate the prerequisites for bib after running pdflatex as part of lat?

You can somewhat achieve that, by adding `make lat` to the recipe for `bib`. This will start a new make process targetting at `bib`. The sub-make doesn't know anything aboutits parents targets/prerequisites. (Such a concept is usually used, when some huge project is built from different smaller projekts each of which have different makefiles.)

This can be done in multiple layers (although it will be confusing):

```
bib: $(foo)?.aux lat check_for_bib

check_for_bib:
    if grep -q Rerun $(@:.bbl=.log) >/dev/null; then make bib; fi

pdf: lat check_for_bib
    open $(foo).pdf &
```

Note that I had to change some orders of prerequisites. The pseud-code would be something like:

```
latex compilation
while log suggests update:
    update aux
    latex compilation
```

Each iteration of the while loop will take place in a separate make process.